# Determining when $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{\mu^{n(n+1)/2}}$ is finite

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the series
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{\mu^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}
\end{equation}
and I have to show that this series is finite. I tried using the ratio test and the root test but I don't think either are applicable here. Could someone tell me how I could show this series is finite?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $\lambda$ or on $\mu$?

Comment: If $\lambda = \mu = 1$, the series diverges.

Comment: Sorry I should've added that. I need to find the values for $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that this series is finite.

Comment: Why aren't you confident about the root/ratio tests? Both are applicable here and I think they'll work out if you dot your i's and cross your t's. (Hint: $\sqrt[n]{|\mu^{n(n+1)/2}|}=|\mu|^{(n+1)/2}$.)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few days, so I'll follow up on my comment. The cases $\mu=0$ or $\lambda=0$ do not merit further discussion. Recall the root test: given a series $S=\sum a_n$,  compute $L=\limsup\limits _{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$. Then
$$
S\, \begin{cases} \text{converges},& 0\le L<1\\ \text{diverges},& L>1\\ \text{(test is inconclusive)},& L=1 \end{cases}
$$ We can take limit instead of limsup, giving:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{\lambda^n}{\mu ^{n(n+1)/2}}\right|} = |\lambda| \lim_{n\to\infty} {{|\mu| ^{-(n+1)/2}}} = \begin{cases} +\infty,& 0<|\mu|<1\\ |\lambda|\text{ (see below) },& |\mu|=1\\0,& |\mu|>1 \end{cases}
$$If $|\mu|=1$ and $|\lambda|\ne 1$, the root test is conclusive. If, however, $|\mu|=|\lambda|=1$, the series fails the term test and is divergent (usually a result of $1$ from the root test is inconclusive, but here we can actually say something).